# Crontab start as half past hour

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I got this crontab code to run a script on crontab every 15 minutes from 9 to 18 all days except weekends. However I would like to start fro 9:30 instead of 9. Is it there a way to do it?

*/15 9-18 * * 1-5

Comment: You can use [Crontab Guru](http://crontab.guru/) to help you build complex crontab entries; it's what I used to get the answer I submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `30/15` in the minute area should work just fine:

```
30/15 9-18 * * 1-5
```

This will instruct crontab to run your script: “At every 15th minute from 30 through 59 past every hour from 9 through 18 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.”

Comment: This answer is not correct. It runs 9:30, 9:45, 10:30, 10:45, 11:30, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I finally did this, and it works

```
30 9 * * 1-5 
45 9 * * 1-5 
*/15 10-18 * * 1-5
```

However, it needs three crontab entries.

Comment: This needs an explanation