# Can rrule start at half past hour?

Tags: python-dateutil, rrule

Is it possible to create a rrule that runs every 30 minutes but starts and ends at the middle of an  hour? If rrule would accept non-integer parameters like `byhour=range(16.5,19)` that would be great, but unfortunately only integer is accepted.

In my case the times would be 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00 and 18:30 every weekday. All I can do is from 16:00 to 18:30 as follows:

```
from dateutil.rrule import *
from dateutil.parser import parse

list(rrule(MINUTELY, interval=30, count=20, byhour=range(16,19), byminute=(0,30), byweekday=(MO,TU,WE,TH,FR), dtstart=parse("20220602T070000")))
```

...with the following result:

```
[datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 16, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 16, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 16, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 16, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 16, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 16, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 7, 16, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 7, 16, 30)]
```

I was hoping rrule has more flexibility than [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596931)...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `rrset.exrule`:

```
from dateutil.rrule import *
from dateutil.parser import parse

myrrule = rrule(MINUTELY, interval=30, count=20, byhour=range(16,19), byminute=(0,30), byweekday=(MO,TU,WE,TH,FR), dtstart=parse("20220602T070000"))
myexrule = rrule(DAILY, interval=1, count=4, byhour=16, byminute=0, byweekday=(MO,TU,WE,TH,FR), dtstart=parse("20220602T070000"))

rrset = rruleset()
rrset.rrule(myrrule)
rrset.exrule(myexrule)

list(rrset)
```

with the following result:

```
[datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 16, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 2, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 16, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 3, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 16, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 17, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 17, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 18, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 6, 18, 30),
 datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 7, 16, 30)]
```